# SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, localhost

I can't connect the postgreSQL using sequelize and node.js. When I upload the application to the vps

ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at Client._connectionCallback (/root/server/mern-cloud-disk-server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:131:24)
at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/root/server/mern-cloud-disk-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:318:19)
at Client._handleErrorEvent (/root/server/mern-cloud-disk-server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:328:19)
at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
at Socket.reportStreamError (/root/server/mern-cloud-disk-server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:57:12)
at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 5432
},
original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 5432
}
}

file db.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
```

```
module.exports = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DB_NAME, // Название БД
    process.env.DB_USER, // Пользователь
    process.env.DB_PASSWORD, // ПАРОЛЬ
    {
        dialect: 'postgres',
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT
    }
)
```

file .env

```
PORT=5000
DB_NAME=auto-service
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=password
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
SECRET_KEY=secret
```

file index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const sequelize = require('./db')
const models = require('./models/models')
const cors = require('cors')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const router = require('./routes/index')
const path = require('path')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')))
app.use(fileUpload({}))
app.use('/api', router)

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    await sequelize.sync()
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

start()
```

Comment: Choose a database name without hyphens, check the docs

Comment: Yes, I did it, but the problem is that everything works locally, and when I try to put it on the Internet, such a problem

Comment: Make sure you are able to connect to Postgres using psql when logged into your VPS, I'm assuming it might be using a different port/password

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.